# Conditional expectation given the comparison with 3 random variables

Tags: definite-integrals, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

T is a continuous variable uniformly distributed between 0 and 100. t, s1,s2 and s3 are randomly chosen numbers from this distribution where t is called the target number.
The value of t, s1 and s2 are not disclosed whereas the value of s3 is publicly known

It is also revealed that s1 is less than or equal to t, s2 is greater than t and less than or equal to 75. Finally, s3 is greater than t.

What is expected value of t conditional on the given information above?

Note that the expected value of t (target number) should be dependent on only s3 since the value of s1 and s2 are not known.

---

I have the solution for the case where two random numbers are drawn to compare with the target number, t. In that case, lets call the random numbers as s1 and s2 where only the value of s2 is disclosed (s1 is unknown).

It is revealed that s1 is less than or equal to t.

If s2 is greater than or equal to target number t, the expected value of t becomes 2*s2/3. The solution can be found via double integral

$\int^{s2}_0$$\int^y_0$$(s2-x)dxdy$/$\int^{s2}_0$$\int^y_0$$dxdy$=$2*s2/3$

If s2 is less than target number t, the expected value of t becomes (2/3)*[$(100+s2)^2$-100*s2]/(100+s2). The solution can be found via double integral or the gravity center of the area.

Comment: It would probably be good to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have the solution for the case where two random numbers are drawn to compare with the target number, t. In that case, the random numbers are called s1 and s2 and only the value of s2 is disclosed. The information that s1 is less than or equal to t is given. The expected value of t becomes 2s2/3 given that s2 is greater than or equal to target number t. The solution can be found via double integral

Comment: This problem cannot be solved unless more information about the joint distribution for $(S_1, S_2, S_3)$ is given.  Are they mutually independent?  Are they uniformly distributed? Do they take integer values or real number values?  Finally, as it seems you are computing an expected value of $t$, then $t$ should be random (perhaps call it $T$) and have a distribution as well. Otherwise, if $t$ is a constant, the expected value of $t$, given any info, is still just $t$.

Comment: Also, your meaning of "pre-determined variable" and "$S_3$ is disclosed" should be clarified in terms of their impact on the question. (For example, are you computing and expectation given $S_3$?)

Comment: S1, S2,S3 are mutually independent and uniformly distributed. They can take any real number between 0 and 100. The question is to find the expected value of t given the information on s1,s2 and s3 and t is also uniformly distributed between 0 and 100 and can take any real number in that range.